# after_create callback and associations create order

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a small doubt regarding `after_create` callback. If I have a model with many associations, `after_create` is getting called before the association objects are actually saved in the database. Is this the behaviour of `after_create` callback?

Comment: Avoid callbacks, use builders

Comment: @apneadiving do you have any specific reason to avoid callbacks?

Comment: @Abhinay besides having predicitible and crystal clear code, not that much

Comment: @Abhinay more seriously there are tons of blog posts about this, but the most important thing is to realize callbacks depend on a context and you can abstract contexts. Then your model doesnt have any more magic and is easier to work with (no more conditionals in callbacks) and to test

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `after_create` will always gets executed first, followed by `after_save`. This is where you will find your answer with better explanation, specifically in section 3.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

**PS**: Please ask those questions which can be solved or solution of which can be shown with some piece of codes. try to figure out theoretical concepts on your own unless its a really complex algorithm which again needs an explanation using a piece of code.